# change the way i query the database in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdo

I write Object-Oriented PHP, but recently I started learning CodeIgniter.

Problem is I have to use different syntax for each (when querying the database).

When writing OOP code I usually do this:

```
public function insertAdvert() {

    $query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO rooms (title, description, postcode) VALUES (?, ?)");

    $query->bindValue(1, $this->title);
    $query->bindValue(2, $this->description);
    $query->execute();

}
```

And for CodeIgniter:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO rooms (title, description) VALUES (?,?);"; 
$this->db->query($sql, array($this->title, $this->description));
```

Is there a way to query the database in CodeIgniter by using prepared statements? Both methods start to blend in and that's not good:/

Answer (score 2):

By default, the answer is "no". Codeigniter has its own query syntax and you can't bind values/parameters like you can with straight PDO.

However, there is a third-party modification that would allow you to use true PDO syntax in Codeigniter, which can be found [here](http://christopherickes.com/web-app-development/pdo-for-codeigniter-2/).

It involves replacing one of the core Codeigniter files, which is generally discouraged, but if you're up to it, give it a try.